# How to replace starting number of N spaces to number of N+2 space?

Tags: regex, sed

I use sed to do this work. Here is my script:

```
sed 's/^(      )([^ ]+)$/\1  \2/g' -i main.js
```

It doesn't  work. This is the error infomation:

```
sed: 1: "s/^(      )([^ ]+)$/\1  ...": \1 not defined in the RE
```

Comment: Try putting the `-r` option, then you don't need to escape the capture groups.

Comment: it is not `-r` but `-E` option which is extended regexp

Comment: `-r` is for GNU sed only.

Comment: @ruibin It depends on the system hence the word "try". On my system `-r` is documented yet either works, so perhaps `-E` is a better way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Basic sed uses BRE, you need to escape `(`, `)`, `+`

```
sed 's/^\(      \)\([^ ]\+\)$/\1  \2/g' -i main.js
```

or

```
sed 's/^\([[:blank:]]\+\)/\1  /'  main.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a capture group. If you want to repeat the whole match in your substitution, you can use `&`:

```
sed -i 's/^      /&  /' main.js
```

This adds two spaces to any lines starting with six spaces, no matter what they're followed by. Notice that the `g` flag doesn't make sense here as by definition, this substitution can only happen once per line.

If you only want to add two spaces to lines starting with six spaces followed by a non-space, you can use

```
sed -i '/^ \{6\}[^ ]/s/^ \{6\}/&  /' main.js
```

which is still a little shorter than capturing and backreferencing. It uses an address (the first `/.../` expression), meaning that the command following it is only executed for lines matching the address; the actual command starts with `s` and is the normal substitution.

Comment: It is difficult to understand.Because substitution flag `s` is in the middle and has too many `/`

Comment: @ruibin I'll add some more explanations.